# jqDialog alert issue with newline character(\n)

Tags: php, jquery

there's problem with my jqdialog. Like this:

```
jQuery.jqDialog.alert("To accept the terms of policy, click 'OK' <br/>"+"<?php if(isset($provider_terms)) echo $provider_terms; else echo 'No policy used.' ?>", function() { });
```

In `$provider_terms` there's string with "\n". and because of that the dialogbox doesn't seems.
Any help can be appreaciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
echo nl2br($provider_terms);
```

Comment: ok so what error do you get? what does it render? Check the page source and see if ther're some `'` or `"` breaking the javascript

Comment: it doesn't even seen in page source !!

Comment: @Manuel- it skips whole jqdialog alert line. I think it might be problem with jqdialog only.

Comment: that's weird.. can you try replacing the line for `$.jqDialog.alert("This is a non intrusive alert");`

Comment: @Manuel if I don't include "\n" then it works perfectly fine.